# alternative to basic authentication for nginx-unit?

Tags: linux, http, nginx, nginx-unit

I have `nginx-unit` server.

I don't use `nginx`, because my application is fully dynamic and test purpose products.

However it doesn't have basic authentication like apache.

Is there any alternative to basic authentication on `nginx-unit` ??

I should use `nginx`?? if so, is there any alternativce to basic authentication??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong kerberos authentication works well if you don't want to use basic auth and your use case applies. You can use sssd with Samba to make it work.

Comment: Thank you kerberos could be the good choice. I will check details

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking something simple (like checking name-values in URI) for authentication than you can try to use [matching in routing](http://unit.nginx.org/configuration/#matching-conditions).